# How to place categorical labels on right side of barchart?

Tags: r, lattice

In the default Lattice barchart, categorical variable labels are placed on the left.  I want to put them on the right as well.  I can manipulate locations of numeric ticks and labels using `scales`, but have had no success in moving the categorical labels.  Study of `help(barchart)` and Sarkar's book has not led to the answer (which is not to say the answer isn't there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with the `scales` argument. Try adding `alternating = 3` to the list of y scale parameters.

```
barchart(variety ~ yield, data = barley, groups = year, stack = TRUE,
         ylab = "Barley Yield (bushels/acre)",
         scales = list(x = list(rot = 45), y = list(alternating = 3)),
         horizontal = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  I think I tried using `alternating=3`, but put it at the top level inside the list in `scales=list()`, rather than inside another list in `y=list()`.